# How to make bar charts and scatter dots appear underneath each other?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

In chart js is it possible to have each bar exactly under each scatter dot? in below images the first one correct and second one is not.

[image]

[image]

You can check demo here [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-blackburn-4gjur?file=/src/MyChart.js)

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on a per-case basis. The problem is that both charts have different `xAxis` type ([linear](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-cartesian-axis) and [category](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html#category-cartesian-axis)). Also the `yAxis` labels are of different length.

To solve the problem on the chart from your demo, you can change the options from your  scatter chart as follows.

> 1. Define option `scales.xAxes.offset: true` to make it correspond to the [default value defined for bar charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#scale-configuration).
> 2. Add `min` and `max` to `scales.xAxes.ticks` to horizontally adjust the points with the bars.

```
scales: {
   xAxes: [{
       offset: true, 
       gridLines: {
         display: false
       },
       ticks: {
         min: -0.2, 
         max: 3.3,
```

Please have a look at your [**amended Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-brook-ws9sp?file=/src/MyChart.js:3209-3394).

Comment: thanks it helped alot, but if the data increase it doesn't work quite well for example if I have `const  data = [
  {
    effect: 1.0,
    likes: 84.64,
    name: "Price of fish"
  },
  {
    effect: -1,
    likes: -20.39,
    name: "Holiday"
  },
  {
    effect: 1,
    likes: 14.58,
    name: "Weather "
  },
  {
    effect: null,
    likes: 0,
    name: "Interest "
  },
  {
    effect: null,
    likes: 0,
    name: "Shopping"
  },
  {
    effect: 0,
    likes: 5,
    name: "Cart"
  }
];` it wouldn't work (modified the max but can't do more changes on min)